# what's the right way to set entity fields from optional fields in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

i'm using the following pattern in symfony

```
        if (!empty($pssItem["ip"])) $bookingAdditionalInfo->setIpAddress($pssItem["ip"]);
        if (!empty($pssItem["ipLocation"])) $bookingAdditionalInfo->setIpAddressLocation($pssItem["ipLocation"]);
        if (!empty($pssItem["userAgent"])) $bookingAdditionalInfo->setUserAgent($pssItem["userAgent"]);
        if (!empty($pssItem["utmCampaign"])) $bookingAdditionalInfo->setUtmCampaign($pssItem["utmCampaign"]);
        if (!empty($pssItem["utmChannel"])) $bookingAdditionalInfo->setUtmChannel($pssItem["utmChannel"]);
        if (!empty($pssItem["utmMedium"])) $bookingAdditionalInfo->setUtmMedium($pssItem["utmMedium"]);
        if (!empty($pssItem["utmSource"])) $bookingAdditionalInfo->setUtmSource($pssItem["utmSource"]);
```

is there a way to make this beautiful ?

Answer (score -1):

I'd start by addressing the inconsistencies:

The `ip` parameter uses the `setIpAddress` method, and the `ipLocation` parameter uses the `setIpAddressLocation` method.

Once you address the inconsistencies, such as by setting up setIp and setIpAddress methods, you could move over to a loop:

```
$keys = [
    'ip', 'ipLocation', 'userAgent',
    'utmCampaign', 'utmChannel', 'utmMedium', 'utmSource'
    // note you may want to include other utm possibilities here

];

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    if (!empty($pssItem[$key])) {
        $bookingAdditionalInfo->{'set'.ucfirst($key)}($pssItem[$key]);
    }
}
```

You might also consider storing such parameters as an array rather than a series of functional calls.

```
$bookingAdditionalInfo->setParameters($pssItem)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$reflect          = new \ReflectionClass($bookingAdditionalInfo);    
$propertyAccessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();

foreach ($reflect->getProperties() as $property) {
    $propertyName = $property->getName();

    if (!empty($pssItem[$propertyName])) {
        $propertyAccessor->setValue($bookingAdditionalInfo, $property, $pssItem[$propertyName]);
    }
}
```

But you should change mismatching properties or array keys, like `ipAddressLocation` and `ipLocation`